# Java Scanner hasNextDouble() doesn't work properly after the first instance

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In my program I'm taking three seperate doubles as input to three variables.  I want to test for the error condition when the input is not a double.  However if I put the string "test" in as the first variable, the program outputs the prompt for the two other variables but does not give the option for input, and quickly prints out the error message.

My question is why does it only take the first failed input and skip testing the other two?

Code:

```
/*
 * This program reads three numbers and provides the following
 * conditional outputs:
 * "all the same" if all the same
 * "all different" if they are all different
 * "neither" in all other cases
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P3d4 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //initialize variables
        double number1 = 0;
        double number2 = 0;
        double number3 = 0;
        boolean failTest = false;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt and take input for the three numbers, flagging for
        //invalid doubles

        System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
        if (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            number1 = in.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            failTest = true;
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
        if (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            number2 = in.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            failTest = true;
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the third number: ");
        if (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            number3 = in.nextDouble();
        }
        else
        {
            failTest = true;
        }

        //output error if one or more values are invalid,
        //otherwise output comparison results
        if (failTest == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: One or more of the values are not valid.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (number1 == number2 && number2 == number3)
            {
                System.out.println("The numbers are all the same.");
            }
            else if (number1 != number2 && number2 != number3 && number1 != number3)
            {
                System.out.println("The numbers are all different.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The numbers are neither all different or all the same.");
            }
        }


    }

}
```

The following output is seen if testing a failing input:

```
Please enter the first number: test
Please enter the second number: Please enter the third number: Error: One or more of the values are not valid.
```

Comment: paste the output of your program...or just run it in a debugger

Comment: Please enter the first number: test
Please enter the second number: Please enter the third number: Error: One or more of the values are not valid.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not formatting the output properly here.  There is a newline after "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `in.nextDouble()`, your program checks to see if `in` has a token, which it does not, so - like all the `Scanner.hasNext__()` methods - it waits until it gets one. When you give it the String input "test", `in` now has a token and therefore proceeds. At that point, `in.nextDouble()` checks to see if that token is a double, which it is not.

I think where you're confused is that you think `in.nextDouble()` then sits around waiting until it gets a double. It doesn't. It only waits if `in` has no token at all. As long as `in` has a token, it evaluates that token to see if it's a double. If it is, it removes and processes it. If not, it simply returns false *without removing the current token*.

When you get to your second call to `in.hasNextDouble()`, once again it checks to see if `in` has a token. This time it does, so - without waiting for further input - it checks to see if that token    is a `double`, which it is not - it's still the string "test". Your `println()` statements are outside of your conditionals, which is why your prompts print, but only your `else` blocks are executed because "test" remains the current token and therefore all your calls to `hasNextDouble()` return false.

**Edit (in response to another answer)** I agree entirely with @AmirAfghani's suggestion. What you're doing with your conditionals(and maybe even your usage of `hasNextDouble()` instead of simply `hasNext()`) is unclear and leads me to think you're confused about a few things. That said, you asked for an explanation of what's going on here - so here you go :)

**Edit (in response to your comment)** If by "reset it" you mean remove the current token so that the scanner waits again on the second block, this can be achieved by calling simply `in.next()`, which will remove the current token without checking its type.

Comment: Is there a way to reset in before testing it again?

Answer (score 1):

what drewmore said is correct,
a simple fix is to add `in.next();` into the first 2 `else` statements like so:

```
    System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
    if (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
        number1 = in.nextDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        failTest = true;
        in.next();
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");

    if (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
        number2 = in.nextDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        failTest = true;
        in.next();
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter the third number: ");

    if (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
        number3 = in.nextDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        failTest = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  Now I see drewmore perfectly answered my question, but I am too much of a newb to realize it until it's spelled out for me!